# Command line utility for the LibreOffice Mythes library

Tags: command-line, openoffice, libreoffice, thesaurus, hunspell

(Open|Libre)Office provides a thesaurus using the Myth library.

Is there a command line tool to access these thesaurus data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [download package for mythes](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hunspell/files/MyThes/) contains an "example" application that may act as command line tool. I didn't test it, but i think it's worth a try if it works with the hunspell `.idx`/`.dat` files after compiling it.

Comment: That's a good start indeed. Not a full tool, but surely something usable already.